# Java object comparison and Hashtable with Object keys

Tags: java

Suppose I have an `MyObject` class, and it's stored in 2 different `ArrayList`. If get the same object from the 2 ArrayList, how would I compare them to check if they're identical?

Would I do `instance1 == instance2` or `instance1.equals(instance2)`? I'm pretty sure the == operator looks at the pointer location, but if I get instance1 from array1 and instance2 from array2, would they return different pointer locations or the same?

Same thing with Hashtable: Does it store a pointer location as the key or the actual object? If I have 2 objects with identical content but are actually different objects, would it still work?

Thanks

Comment: The last part of your question is extremely unclear - please edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: Yeah, edited. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> ***if I get instance1 from array1 and instance2 from array2, would they return different pointer locations or the same?***

Yes, if they are referring to the same object, `==` will return true.

An ArrayList will store precisely what you give to it. If you give it a reference ("address") it will store that address. When you fetch the that particular element, you'll get the same reference back.

Sample snippet:

```
Object o = new Object();

List<Object> l1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Object> l2 = new ArrayList<Object>();

l1.add(o);
l2.add(o);

Object o1 = l1.get(0);
Object o2 = l2.get(0);

System.out.println(o1 == o2); // prints true
```

In a sense the ArrayList *does* however make a copy (of the reference!) As this snippet illustrates, the list is not affected when changing `s`:

```
String s = "hello";
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add(s);
s = "world";
System.out.println(l.get(0));  // prints hello
```

---

Basically `==` compares content of variables. Since the content of a reference is an "address", comparing references using `==` will yield true if and only if the two references refer to the same object.

`o1.equals(o2)` on the other hand compares the actual objects which `o1` and `o2` refer to.

---

> ***Does it store a pointer location as the key or the actual object? If I have 2 objects with identical content but are actually different objects, would it still work?***

It uses the actual object as key. If you have two separate objects which are `equal`, then you can use either one to retrieve the value stored for that key.

---

> ***I'm pretty sure the == operator looks at the pointer location***

This is nitpicking, but, no, `==` looks at pointer *content*, or *object* locations.

Comment: I can see that this works, but since l1 and l2 are individual objects wouldn't they each have a different memory address?  Do List/primitive array '==' differ from normal object comparison?

Comment: No, there's nothing special with `List` or arrays. Both lists and arrays are objects, and when you have variables containing references to such objects, `==` works just as with any other references.

Comment: RTFC.  I thought it said (l1 == l2) not what you wrote.  Thanks for the clarification regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You need to differentiate between *objects* and *references*.

Two different lists (or in general, any expressions) can be equal *references* to the same object. For example:

```
MyObject x = new MyObject();
MyObject y = x;
```

Here `x` and `y` are separate variables but they both have values referring to the same object. That "referring to the same object" is what `==` will compare.

If you use `equals` then (assuming you've overridden `equals` in `MyObject`) two *different* objects can still be equal.

For example:

```
Integer x = new Integer(1);
Integer y = new Integer(1);
System.out.println(x == y); // False
System.out.println(x.equals(y)); // True
```

Here the values of `x` and `y` are references to different objects, but those objects are considered to be equal.

So, does your `MyClass` class have a notion of object equality beyond just "object identity"? Which aspect are you interested in when you compare the references stored in the lists?

Comment: I know that, However, I need to know whether or not the ArrayList takes reference or creates a new object.

Comment: @ultimatebuster: Well that's not what you *asked* at all - but no, collections in Java don't automatically clone objects. You pass a *reference* into the `add` method (or whatever) and that reference is added to the list. If you want to create a clone, you have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If the same object has been stored in two separate `ArrayList` containers and you want to check whether they are identical, use the `==` operator to check for object identity.

This will work since only the references are stored in the `ArrayList`.